# Relationship between sequence of diffeomorphisms and the sequence itself

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, geometry, analysis

Let $F:D_1\to \mathbb{C}$ be a diffeomorphism and suppose that for each $n$, $g_n:X \to D_1\subset \mathbb{C}$ is measurable with $X$ a probability space with $\dim(X)=1$ (e.g $X=S^1$). This defines our sequence of functions of concern.

If $\mathrm{ess\ sup}_X|F(g_n(x))-F(g(x))|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, is it true that $\mathrm{ess\ sup}_X|g_n(x)-g(x)|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$?

- I believe that this statement is true since $|F(g_n(x))-F(g(x))|$ simply compares distances in $\mathbb{C}$, whereas $|g_n(x)-g(x)|$ is comparing the distances in $D_1$.
- How about the converse of this statement? I suspect this may not be true as one could define a sequence $g_n(x)$ converging on $S^1$ where the diffeomorphism $F$ is undefined.
- Would changing the regularity of the functions $g_n$ change the answer? I don't think it would since the $\mathrm{ess\ sup}$ would change to supremum or minimum.

Comment: You might want to specify what kind if object $X$ is. Is it a manifold with a measure on it? Is it a vector space? If so, is it a complex vector space or a real one? What about the codomain of $F$ ? By the invariance of domain, $F$ cannot be a diffeo onto the entire complex plane.

Comment: @Lukic I have hopefully made the question a bit better. Here $F$ is defined to be the diffeomorphism mapping the unit disk to the entire complex plain.